# Switch owa mobile to desktop view

Tags: outlook-web-access

Is there a way to use outlook web app on my mobile device displaying the normal, desktop interface? The mobile view is totally useless to me.

I have pretty good eyes, my Iphone has a pretty good resolution, and I'd rather zoom in and out than use that horrid mobile interface.

No, I don't want to download the app.

Using Ios9, Opera Coast or Safari browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: This question would better suited at Web applications.

Comment: Thanks @RookieTEC9, didn't know about that place. I'll use it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your mobile browser, there is often a way to select an option such as "Use desktop version" of a browser page. In Opera Coast, go to 'Settings / Advanced / User agent' and change to 'Desktop' to fool the browser serving the pages into serving you up the desktop pages.

In Safari for mobile, in iOS 9 you can hold down the reload icon in the address bar (top right) and then select "Request Desktop Site". You can also tap the share icon (bottom of browser, next to forward arrow), then scroll across to "Request Desktop Site".